# Why one function fires but the other one dosn't? [React]

Tags: reactjs

Working in ReactJS

I have a button that toggles a section but I want also to auto scroll to that section, I have a fixed nav so I need to also offset the scroll.

I can't make 2 calls work in side onClick:

```
onClick={handleClick, ()=>{ setToggle(1)}}
```

this way setToggle function runs but handleClick doesn't.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try to call methods like below:-

```
onClick={(event) => { 
   handleClick(event);
   setToggle(1);
}}
```

Comment: setToggle has underline with ';' expected

Comment: when I add ";" I cant access event that's passed in to handleClick.
"Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

Comment: If you are using multiple functions inside an element - consider margin them into one function:

const handleClick = (e) => {
 // do some stuff
setToggle(1)
}

Comment: @Ferinecko I have updated my answer can you please check again?